# Network profile name different from per se name

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, network-profile

The user amWhy used to be an active participant on Math.SE.  Here's their network profile.

[image: amWhy's SE network profile]

I clicked on his/her per-site profiles, and *each* of them showed their *new* user name Namaste.

[image: amWhy's Math.SE profile]

You may click on the screenshots to browse amWhy/Namaste's user profile.

How is this possible?  One is allowed to have multiple names on the SE network?

My attempt:

Site user profiles have a link "*Edit Profile & Settings*" for changing user name.  At the bottom of the HTML form, one may choose to update user profile for either one or all communities.  After that, to apply such change to the SE network profile, one may click "*Update profile info*" in the network-wide page.  It seems that amWhy has changed their user name and clicked "*Save and copy changes to all public communities*", so such change should be network-wide, and it's bizarre that the network profile user name has not been updated.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah. You can set your username differently on each site.

Comment: @Catija Thanks for quick response.  However, I'm still scratching my head on the possibility that the network-wide user name is different from per se user name due to my proposed reason in the last section.

Comment: @animuson Is my answer correct, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Unrelated FYI: given that they are suspended for voting irregularities, if they go on to delete their account, it could result in a massive vote invalidation.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I'm refering to the profiles of one single user amWhy.  Why did you change "his/her" to "their"?

Comment: Because in informal English, ["their" is a valid singular pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). It also takes into account the fact that users may be non-binary.

Comment: @Sonic Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Network profiles are cached, and that cache is only updated manually when the user resyncs it with information from a specific site.

In this case, even though the user copied a new name to their site profiles, their network profile won't be updated until the user manually resyncs it themselves (or an employee does it for them).